# Can i use the flutter_form_builder_package with stateless widgets and provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-form-builder

Im using the package [flutter_form_builder](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder)
I have alredy made a few screens with forms, with stateless widgets and provider, each screen has its own provider with submit methods etc.
Everithing was working okay until i test my theme, changing to dark mode on ios from control center, rebuilds the entire app and the form loses its data, but the provider does not lose its data. This does not happen with stateful widgets.
My question is, theres a way to keep the data across rebuilds whitout stateful widgets?, i have tried storing the formkey on the provider but this doesnt work, i got errors about duplicated key. I have alredy made my test files thinking with stateless widgets. If my provider does not lose its data, i suppose there is a way to save the form state on the provider, because the need to convert to stateful widgets it the form state.
Sorry, im new on flutter and i learning english too.